# Is there a way to abort a call to model.fit?

Tags: tensorflow.js

I want a button on my web page to abort an ongoing training. I realise that a callback provided to FIT can throw an exception so that it will abort when the epoch or batch ends but is there a way to abort it immediately?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to **immediately** stop the training process through the Tensorflow.js API. That said, you can spawn your own process to run the training, which you can kill anytime.

#### Using the Tensorflow.js API

To abort a running training of a model, you can set `model.stopTraining` to `true`. Tensorflow.js only checks after each batch if this variable is set. Therefore, there is no way to interrupt the training process directly by using the Tensorflow.js API.

**Code Sample**

```js
await model.fit(x, y, {
    callbacks: {
        onBatchEnd: (batch, logs) => { // stop after batch
            if (/* ... */) {
                model.stopTraining = true;
            }
        },
        onEpochEnd: (epoch, logs) => { // stop after epoch
            if (/* ... */) {
                model.stopTraining = true;
            }
        },
    },
});
```

To directly abort the training process without waiting for the batch to finish, you have to kill the process itself.

#### Killing the training by killing the process

Killing the process means you need to separate your script into two individual parts. One part is the "managing" process keeping track of the first one and the other one does the actual training.

**In the browser environment**

In the browser you can use a WebWorker to run your training and then call [`worker.terminate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Worker/terminate) to kill the running process. However, it is not that easy to start the training process inside a web worker as you need to transfer your data and use an [OffscreenCanvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OffscreenCanvas) (when using WebGL). Check out this [github issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/102) for more information.

**Using Node.js**

In the Node.js environment, it's easier. You can spawn a process using [`child_process.spawn`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) and kill it by calling [`process.kill`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_subprocess_kill_signal). You still have to come up with a communication scheme for the processes, but as your training process can read the data itself, the overhead should not be that big. That said, it is sill a very sophisticated task for *just* stopping the training.

Comment: Thanks this is very helpful. Shouldn't model.stopTraining be documented at https://js.tensorflow.org/api/latest/?

Comment: @ToonTalk This is currently not well documented. I only found out about this myself when I was in the same situation as you and looking at how [callbacks.earlyStopping works](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-layers/blob/v1.2.7/src/callbacks.ts#L182).